# Work with external library: angular-socialshare

Tags: javascript, angularjs, sharing, socialshare

I'm a beginner in programming and I am trying to work with the external lib `angular-socialshare`. Unfortunately, I failed at it. It should be possible to share some content via facebook without using jquery.

I downloaded the lib and added to my html-file:

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.4/angular.min.js"></script>
<script src="vendors/angular-socialshare/dist/angular-socialshare.js"></script>
```

I also added:

```
<div ng-controller='myCtrl'> <div socialshare socialshare-provider="facebook" 
    socialshare-url="http://720kb.net" facebook class="facebookShare"</div> </div>
```

In my js-file I wrote:

```
 var myApp = angular.module('myApp', [
      '720kb.socialshare',
    ]);
    myApp.controller("myCtrl", ['Socialshare', function testController(Socialshare) {
      Socialshare.share({
        'provider': 'facebook',
        'attrs': {
          //fill attributes
         },
      });
    }]);
```

I think it is missing the ng-app but as soon as I add ng-app="myApp" at the div I get this error:

> Error: [$injector:modulerr] 
>   http://errors.angularjs.org/1.6.4/$injector/modulerr?
>   p0=myApp&p1=%5B%24injector%3Anomod%5D%20http%3A%2F%2Ferrors.angularjs.org%2F1.6.4%2F%24injector%2Fnomod%3Fp0%3DmyApp%0AL%2F%3C%40https%3A%2F%2Fajax.googleapis.com%2Fajax%2Flibs%2Fangularjs%2F1.6.4%2Fangular.min.js%3A6%3A425%0AAe%2F%3C%2F%3C%2F%3C%40https%3A%2F%2Fajax.googleapis.com%2Fajax%2Flibs%2Fangularjs%2F1.6.4%2Fangular.min.js%3A26%3A270%0Ab%40https%3A%2F%2Fajax.googleapis.com%2Fajax%2Flibs%2Fangularjs%2F1.6.4%2Fangular.min.js%3A25%3A299%0AAe%2F%3C%2F%3C%40https%3A%2F%2Fajax.googleapis.com%2Fajax%2Flibs%2Fangularjs%2F1.6.4%2Fangular.min.js%3A26%3A44%0Ag%2F%3C%40https%3A%2F%2Fajax.googleapis.com%2Fajax%2Flibs%2Fangularjs%2F1.6.4%2Fangular.min.js%3A42%3A117%0Aq%40https%3A%2F%2Fajax.googleapis.com%2Fajax%2Flibs%2Fangularjs%2F1.6.4%2Fangular.min.js%3A7%3A493%0Ag%40https%3A%2F%2Fajax.googleapis.com%2Fajax%2Flibs%2Fangularjs%2F1.6.4%2Fangular.min.js%3A41%3A476%0Aeb%40https%3A%2F%2Fajax.googleapis.com%2Fajax%2Flibs%2Fangularjs%2F1.6.4%2Fangular.min.js%3A46%3A44%0Ac%40https%3A%2F%2Fajax.googleapis.com%2Fajax%2Flibs%2Fangularjs%2F1.6.4%2Fangular.min.js%3A21%3A373%0ASc%40https%3A%2F%2Fajax.googleapis.com%2Fajax%2Flibs%2Fangularjs%2F1.6.4%2Fangular.min.js%3A22%3A179%0Aue%40https%3A%2F%2Fajax.googleapis.com%2Fajax%2Flibs%2Fangularjs%2F1.6.4%2Fangular.min.js%3A20%3A406%0A%40https%3A%2F%2Fajax.googleapis.com%2Fajax%2Flibs%2Fangularjs%2F1.6.4%2Fangular.min.js%3A331%3A117%0Ab%40https%3A%2F%2Fajax.googleapis.com%2Fajax%2Flibs%2Fangularjs%2F1.6.4%2Fangular.min.js%3A38%3A36%0A

Can anybody help me with my problem? I really don't understand how to work with this library.

Comment: Why do you load the module **before** angularjs?

Comment: @AlonEitan What exactly do you mean? How to load angularjs? I tried to do it like described there: https://www.w3schools.com/angular/angular_intro.asp

Comment: @AlonEitan or do you mean the order of the scirpt-tags? I accidently mixed them up in my question. I corrected it.

Comment: In that case, you should open the developer tools, go to the network tab, refresh the page and then you'll see all the files\assets that are loaded - Check if there's an error (404 maybe) for the `vendors/angular-socialshare/dist/angular-socialshare.js` file